# AngularJS: How do I autofocus a list of elements one at a time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This Mad-Libs type game is my first AngularJS app. The user is presented with a list of boxes (generated with `ng-repeat`), one at a time (thanks to `ng-show`), in which to input their words. I would like to have each box focused when it appears. I downloaded the module `focus-if`, which seems to work... for all items but the first one. How can I get the first list item to autofocus?

Below are the relevant HTML div and relevant AngularJS module code. GitHub link is https://github.com/amcooper/ftfy_speeches.

HTML (note the `focus-if` expression in the input tag):

```
<div id="fillings" ng-show="speechList.panel=='fillingsPanel'">
    <h3 class="text-center">{{speechList.selected.name}}</h3>
    <h4 class="text-center">{{speechList.selected.author_first_name}} {{speechList.selected.author_surname}}</h4>
    <div class="eachFilling" ng-repeat="filling in speechList.selected.fillings track by $index">
        <b><i><span class="counter" ng-show="speechList.fillingsCounter==$index">{{$index+1}} of {{speechList.selected.fillings.length}}</span></i></b>
        <input type="text" name="filling" id="filling"+{{$index+1}}.toString() class="filling" placeholder="{{filling.pos}}" focus-if="speechList.fillingsCounter==$index" ng-show="speechList.fillingsCounter==$index" ng-model="filling.text" ng-keyup="($event.keyCode==13 && !($last) && speechList.fillingsNext()) || ($event.keyCode==13 && $last && speechList.fillingsSubmit())" />
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" type="submit" ng-show="(speechList.fillingsCounter==$index) && !($last)" ng-click="speechList.fillingsNext()">Next</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm pull-right" type="submit" ng-show="(speechList.fillingsCounter==$index) && $last" ng-click="speechList.fillingsSubmit()">Finished</button>
    </div>
</div> <!-- fillings -->
```

AngularJS module:

```
(function() {
    var app = angular.module('speechChoices', ['focus-if','ngSanitize']);

    app.controller('SpeechListController', function() {
        this.listSubmit = function(clickedIndex) {
            //Perhaps validate choice before submitting<br>here? or have default choice.
            this.speechIndex = clickedIndex;
            this.panel = "fillingsPanel";
            this.selected = speeches[this.speechIndex];
            console.log("status: " + this.panel + "; index: " + this.speechIndex);
        };
        this.fillingsSubmit = function() {
            this.panel = "resultsPanel";
            var j = 0;
            this.htmlResult = "";
            while (j < this.selected.fillings.length) {
                this.htmlResult = this.htmlResult + this.selected.text_snippets[j] + this.selected.fillings[j].text;
                j++;
            }
            this.htmlResult = this.htmlResult + this.selected.text_snippets[this.selected.text_snippets.length-1];
        };
        this.fillingsNext = function() {
            this.fillingsCounter ++;
        };
        this.initialize = function() {
            console.log("Initializing...");
            speeches.forEach(function(el,i,ar) {
                el.fillings.forEach(function(elf,indexf,arf) {
                    elf.text="";
                });
            });
            this.speeches = speeches;
            this.panel = "listPanel";
            this.speechIndex = 0;
            this.selected = speeches[this.speechIndex];
            this.fillingsCounter = 0;
            console.log("status: " + this.panel + "; index: " + this.speechIndex);
        };
        this.initialize();
    });

    var speeches = [{
// an array of speech hashes 
    }];
})();
```

Comment: `ng-repeat` won't be used for this; it's only used for rendering content.

Comment: Yes, right; perhaps the title is misleading & I should edit it.